# Apache rewrite for .png files

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am working with a system accessed by multiple tenants.

Ideally I need to display different logo .png files for different customers.

To remain using a single site, I would like to use Virtualhosts and ServerName functions to identify which client connects and then rewrite the default logo file to a more specific file.

i.e when connecting using customer1.example.com you get customerlogo1.png, but when connecting to customer2.example.com you get customerlogo2.png. I tried the below but it doesn't work.

Can anyone help? It would be much appreciated.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName customer1.example.com
DocumentRoot /usr/share/customers/www
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteRule ^customerlogo1.png$ customerlogo2.png
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName customer2.example.com
DocumentRoot /usr/share/customers/www
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Since the domains are served from different directories (`/usr/share/customer1/www` and `/usr/share/customer2/www`), couldn't you just upload a different image to each domain?

Comment: Yes sorry. The actual sites are the same. Code corrected.

Comment: Oh, OK :-) I think in `<VirtualHost>` statements, you have to include the initial forward slash in the match string. See if this works: `RewriteRule ^/customerlogo1.png$ /customerlogo2.png`.

Comment: no luck. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This if I understand you?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName customer1.example.com
DocumentRoot /usr/share/customers/www
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^customerlogo\.png$ customerlogo1.png [L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName customer2.example.com
DocumentRoot /usr/share/customers/www
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^customerlogo\.png$ customerlogo2.png [L]
</VirtualHost>
```

In your HTML document, you use the same generic customerlogo.png.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Tried it and no luck. Both sites still get the default logo. Is there a way to check if rewrite is working? the module is enabled, but just wondering if that config is ok, could it be something else?